# Any chance of an API for GAE - Application Settings?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a multi-tenancy paid-for app, that I've been running in production for 18 months now.  In the last few months I've been tweaking the runtime configuration to get the best performance for my buck.
I think I've found a fairly optimal solution, involving some idle instances, max instance, reserved hours etc etc.

My clients are generally European based at the moment, so I find myself turning my idle servers on for a European day, and off again at night.
This is a manual chore I'd clearly much rather do without, as its time-consuming and error-prone.
I don't intend to spend any less money, as my budgets are already set according to my client-numbers, I'm just optimising the response times they get based on their time-zones.
I'm sure I can't be alone in wanting such automated configuration, and I'm hoping it would be fairly simple to implement.

Question is, are there any plans to release an API for control of these settings?

Comment: Questions like this are better directed at the mailing list, since they're of a speculative, no-right-answer nature.

Comment: I'd also create a feature request on the issue tracker (http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request) and gather support there.

Comment: ok guys, thanks, will do.  I was trying to be a good boy and migrate away from using that deprecated list, but will post there too.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7436 please star if you'd also like this feature.